# Auth0 and localStorage

Tags: angular, auth0

In the `Auth0` quickstart for Angular2, the code accesses local storage via the following example:

```
localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
```

`localStorage` resolves to type `Storage`.

I don't see where this is defined in the example but it does work.
Can anyone tell me why this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` is a default property on the `window` object. And `Storage` is a standard `JavaScript` object, so no import is necessary.:

[**https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

This applies to `IE>=8`